# punto de intersección entre dos curvas python

Tags: python

Tengo dos funciones en python, son dos curvas y necesito saber en que punto tienen intersección. Que función puedo usar o como puedo realizar esto? Agradezco la ayuda

Comment: ¿Cuáles son tus funciones? ¿Has intentado algo?

Answer (score 0):

Solo necesitas resolver un sistema de ecuaciones. Cada función representa una ecuación, Si las funciones son en 2 dimensiones, tienes que resolver dos ecuación con dos incógnitas.
Por ejemplo dadas las ecuaciones:
     x+y=0
     y+3x-1=0
el código sería:

```
import sympy as sym
x=sym.Symbol('x')
y=sym.Symbol('y')
resp=sym.solve([x+y, y+3*x-1], dict=True)
print(resp)
```

Nota: Para resolver tienes que llevar todos los términos a un lado de la ecuación y el otro miembro tiene que ser 0 (como en el ejemplo)....   y=x se transforma en y-x=0.
Si el resultado es vacío significa que no hay intersección.

Referencias:

[Documentación de sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html) (Tiene algunos ejemplos básicos para resolver ecuaciones)

Comment: En mi comentario anterior, (que borré), me refería a que das un ejemplo para resolver un sistema lineal, el OP no ha especificado cuáles funciones quiere resolver y tampoco ha dicho qué ha intentado para resolverlas. Tu ejemplo está bastante bien, sin embargo yo agregaría una explicación un poco más completa del mismo, y tal vez un enlace a la documentación de `simpy`. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras gracias por la sugerencia, agregué el enlace de simpy. Traté de hacerlo lo más simple posible ya que su problema es más matemático y no así de programación) Ayúdame a editarlo para ver mejorarlo con la información que creas conveniente, aún soy nuevo en esto, Saludos.

Comment: Para empezar pudieras explicar el uso de un `array` para pasar las ecuaciones como parámetro, además puedes aclarar porqué usas la opción `dict = true` y para qué sirve. Por último, puedes explicar brevemente de qué se trata la librería y el porqué puede efectivamente usarse para resolver el problema, es decir, porqué el resultado es la solución al problema. La idea es generar contenido de calidad, para que otras personas puedan encontrar aún más útil tu respuesta. No todos tienen una base matemática, y muchos apenas aprenden a programar. Saludos.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Muchas gracias, en cuanto tenga tiempo completaré todas esas partes) ¡Sí puedes ayudarme a completar esa información sería genial! Sería bueno que como comunidad construyamos “juntos” esa respuesta de calidad. Un abrazo Mauricio

Comment: Muchas gracias, fueron de gran ayuda sus aportes